# getter causes maximum call stack size exceeded flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widget:

```
class VennDiagramWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  VennDiagramWidget(selectedGeneLists);

  List<GenesListObjIndexed> get selectedGeneLists => this.selectedGeneLists;

  @override
  _VennState createState() => _VennState();
}

class _VennState extends State<VennDiagramWidget> {

  List<GenesListObjIndexed> _selectedGeneLists;

  @override
  initState() {
    _selectedGeneLists = widget.selectedGeneLists;
  }
```

This widget is intialized by another widget in this way:

```
.
.
.
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => VennDiagramWidget(selectedGeneLists)));
```

I get and error of `Maximum call stack size exceeded` on this line:
`_selectedGeneLists = widget.selectedGeneLists;` inside `initState`.

To my knowledge, this code is supposed to construct the class `VennDiagramWidget` with the `selectedGeneLists` I have specified on the second snippet, and when I am calling the getter of this class, I should get the exact same variable.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, when you're calling the getter `selectedGeneLists` it's calling itself again

```dart
//                       calling itself ⬇
get selectedGeneLists => this.selectedGeneLists;
```

you need to declare `selectedGeneLists` variable in the widget class

this should work

```dart
class VennDiagramWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final selectedGeneLists;
  VennDiagramWidget(this.selectedGeneLists);

  @override
  _VennState createState() => _VennState();
}
```

or this if you want the variable private

```dart
class VennDiagramWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final _selectedGeneLists;
  VennDiagramWidget(this._selectedGeneLists);

  List<GenesListObjIndexed> get selectedGeneLists => this._selectedGeneLists;

  @override
  _VennState createState() => _VennState();
}
```